# Сменить цвет текста при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, javascript

Есть код, но не работает. Если чекбокс не нажат, и нажимаем на кнопку реги , то цвет текста меняется, но меняться не хочет

```
<a class="reg_button" href="javascript:if(document.getElementById('accept').checked){ registration.submit(); } else { document.getElementById('reg_accept').style.color = "#ff0000"; }">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</a>

<input type='checkbox' name='accept' value='rules' id='accept' class = 'accept' />
<font color="#a9a9a9" id="reg_accept"> Согласен с правилами</font>
```

Comment: а css? не актуально?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам.

```
<a class="reg_button" href="javascript:if(document.getElementById('accept').checked){ registration.submit(); } else { document.getElementById('reg_access').style.color =  '#ff0000'; return false;}">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</a>

<input type='checkbox' name='accept' value='rules' id='accept' class = 'accept' /><div id="reg_access" style="color: #a9a9a9;"> Согласен с правилами</div>
```